# Broadcast an HTML page to clients in Nodejs with Express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, post

I am developing a client-server app with Nodejs and Express. I'd like to send an HTML page (for example `index.html`) to all the clients connected to the server.

The server allows the user to log in with name and password, this connection data are stored with an array just like this:

```
  app.post('/myaction', function(req, res) {

    clients.push({
     "name": req.body.nombre,
    "direction":req.connection.remoteAddress,
     "time": getDate(),
     "role" : role
 });
}
```

So the IP directions are stored in this array too. I can loop with a `forEach` loop:

```
clients.forEach(function (client) {

});
```

Which Express function allows me to send an HTML document to all these clients stored in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't achieve that using express. The best approach is to use websockets to push data to all connected clients. I recommend using [Socket.io](https://socket.io/) for that since it's really simple to use.

```
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);


io.on('connection', socket => {
   console.log('User connected');
});

app.post('/myaction', (req, res) => {
    io.emit('data', 'some-data');

    res.send('Data sent to all connected users');
});
```

**client side**

```
// Add socket.io client side library

var socket = io();
socket.on('data', function(data) {
   // Do something with the data sent from the server
});
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the answer. I think that your solution can work. The client is a web browser, can I use this library from the <script> tag in HTML? The web browser must process the data that receives from the server and print everything in a <div>.

Comment: Yes, the client side code is for a web browser. Just add the socket.io client library using a `<script>` tag and you're done.